# Create an MS Access database file with password from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I want to create an MS Access file `.mdb` by Excel VBA. I want to set a password for this Access file by Excel VBA.

This below code can create Access file but without password.

```
Sub Example1()
    'the path to create the new access database
    Dim strPath As String
    'an Access object
    Dim objAccess As Object

    strPath = "D:\VBA\NewDB2.mdb"
    Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    Call objAccess.NewCurrentDatabase(strPath)
    objAccess.Quit
End Sub
```

How do I set a password?

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CreatePasswordProtectedDatabase()
    Dim strPath As String
    strPath = "D:\VBA\NewDB2.mdb"

    'create new Access application
    Dim objAccess As Object
    Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

    'objAccess.Visible = True 'show or hide Access

    'create new database
    objAccess.NewCurrentDatabase strPath

    'example to add a table
    objAccess.DoCmd.RunSQL "CREATE TABLE Test", False
    objAccess.DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE Test add Gender char(1)", False

    'set password
    Dim DbPassword As String
    DbPassword = "your_password"
    objAccess.CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "ALTER DATABASE PASSWORD " & DbPassword & " NULL"

    'close database
    objAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase

    'quit Access application
    objAccess.Quit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note, if you are using Office 2007 or newer, you must add the `FileFormat` parameter, in order to have your Access file be in mdb format:

```
'create new database
objAccess.NewCurrentDatabase strPath, 10
```

10, being the value of the [`acNewDatabaseFormatAccess2002` constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.acnewdatabaseformat).